# Issue Centering Text within a bottom:0 DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue centering text within a div on my site. Its positioned at the bottom of an image and that working fine, however I cant center the text box.

Page with text: https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/start/adult/picture-yourself/healthy/posts/test.php

The text in question is "The Balance Act"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width: 100%` to your `.cd-headline` class.